# How to generate a mesh with CGAL for a surface defined in a closed parametric form?

Tags: mesh, cgal

I would like to generate a mesh/triangulation for a parametric surfaces with CGAL. This surface is defined by a closed parametric form as can be seen on [this website](http://www.3d-meier.de/tut3/Seite104.html). Note that x, y, and z are defined in terms of two parameters u and v. For such a surface, which is given by a closed parametric form, it should be possible to generate a pretty good mesh/triangulation. I have found several ways to implement it with CGAL (3D Surface Mesh Generation, Surface Reconstruction from Point Sets, ...). My question is which one is appropriate for my special case?